# Display few items in the list TypeScript/React/FluentUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have the following code to display a list of items using Fluent UI DetailsList control. The response includes a total of 200 items. However, I only see 30 items in the list on running the code. What am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Job from './components/Job';

function App() {  
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [err, setError] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://demo4666569.mockable.io/groups')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => setJobs(res))
    .catch(err => setError(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Job jobs={jobs} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DetailsList, DetailsListLayoutMode, IColumn } from '@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList';
import { IJob } from "../interfaces/IJob.interfaces";

export interface IDetailsListBasicExampleProps {
    jobs: IJob[];
  }

export type IDetailsListBasicExampleState = {
  items: IJob[];
}

export default class Job extends React.Component<IDetailsListBasicExampleProps, IDetailsListBasicExampleState> {

  private _allItems: IJob[];
  private _columns: IColumn[];

  constructor(props:IDetailsListBasicExampleProps) {
    super(props);

    this._allItems = props.jobs;   

    this._columns = [
      { key: 'column1', name: 'Identifier', fieldName: 'Identifier', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column2', name: 'ObjectType', fieldName: 'ObjectType', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column3', name: 'InitialOnboardingTime', fieldName: 'InitialOnboardingTime', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column4', name: 'LastAttemptedRunTime', fieldName: 'LastAttemptedRunTime', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column5', name: 'LastSuccessfulRuntime', fieldName: 'LastSuccessfulRuntime', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column6', name: 'EstimatedNextRuntime', fieldName: 'EstimatedNextRuntime', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column7', name: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column8', name: 'ThresholdIncrease', fieldName: 'ThresholdIncrease', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column9', name: 'ThresholdDecrease', fieldName: 'ThresholdDecrease', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
    ];

    this.state = {
      items: this._allItems
    };
  }

    public render(): JSX.Element {

      const { items } = this.state;

        return(

          <div>
            <div> {items.length}</div>
          <br />
            <DetailsList
              items={items}
              columns={this._columns}
              setKey="set"
              layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}              
              selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
              ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
              ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
              checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"              
          />
          <br />
          
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try not to do `<br />` instead use classes on the element before or after with `margin-bottom: 1rem;` or something similar.

Comment: Which version of fluent react are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoid the following anti-pattern:

*"Where the props are used to set the initial state of the Component is a general anti-pattern of React. This implies that the state of the component is tied to the props of the component. The issue with doing this is that **the constructor is only ever called once** in the life cycle of the component. Since the props can change many times during that lifecycle, that implication is broken."*
~ [Read more here](https://sentry.io/answers/using-props-to-initialize-state/) and [here](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e).

You can refactor your code and completely remove the state from the Jobs Component, and pass the jobs data directly through the props:

```
class Job extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._columns = [ ... ];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> {this.props.jobs.length}</div>
        <br />
        <DetailsList
          items={this.props.jobs}
          columns={this._columns}
          setKey="set"
          layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
          selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
          ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
          ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
          checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Secondly, it seems that there are a lot of open Issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/25186) related to the DetailsList Fluent UI Component and React StrictMode.

To make the list show all the data, comment out the `<StrictMode>` *(or probably downgrade to another version of Fluent UI that is not susceptible to that bug. See the threads on GitHub Issues for some suggestions on that)*.

---

Full Source Code:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DetailsList } from "@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList";

class Job extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._columns = [
      {
        key: "column1",
        name: "Identifier",
        fieldName: "Identifier",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column2",
        name: "ObjectType",
        fieldName: "ObjectType",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column3",
        name: "InitialOnboardingTime",
        fieldName: "InitialOnboardingTime",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column4",
        name: "LastAttemptedRunTime",
        fieldName: "LastAttemptedRunTime",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column5",
        name: "LastSuccessfulRuntime",
        fieldName: "LastSuccessfulRuntime",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column6",
        name: "EstimatedNextRuntime",
        fieldName: "EstimatedNextRuntime",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column7",
        name: "Status",
        fieldName: "Status",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column8",
        name: "ThresholdIncrease",
        fieldName: "ThresholdIncrease",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      },
      {
        key: "column9",
        name: "ThresholdDecrease",
        fieldName: "ThresholdDecrease",
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true
      }
    ];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> {this.props.jobs.length}</div>
        <br />
        <DetailsList
          items={this.props.jobs}
          columns={this._columns}
          setKey="set"
          selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
          ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
          ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
          checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => setJobs(res));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Job jobs={jobs} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  // <StrictMode>
  <App />
  // </StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m very new to React, TypeScript. This explanation helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612024/test-for-displaying-a-list-of-items-using-fluent-ui-detailslist-control-in-react

Comment: `comment out the <StrictMode>` work for me.